# error while loading face cascades

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to do face detection in opencv, but every time i try to load cascade classifier it gives me following error:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall cv::CascadeClassifier::~CascadeClassifier(void)" (??1CascadeClassifier@cv@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main`

I don't even understand what it is,can anyone please help me?

```
#include "conio.h"
#include<math.h>
#include "opencv/cvaux.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include"opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include<vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    CascadeClassifier face_cascade,eye_cascade;
    if(!face_cascade.load("D:\\OpenCV2.3\\opencv\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml"))
    {
        printf("\nerror loading face_cascade\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(!eye_cascade.load("D:\\OpenCV2.3\\opencv\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_eye.xml"))
    {
        printf("\nerror loading eye_cascade\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a linker error. Can you include how you are compiling the source? Are you sure you're including opencv libraries?

Comment: add opencv object detection module to your input libraries

Comment: @ian kemp I am including all files...
I use global method for compiling as described in opencv documentation

Comment: link against opencv_objdetect.lib ?

Comment: It's not about *inclusion* at compiling time, it's about *linked libraries* at link time.